# How to increase a progress bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, progress-bar

the question might be seems to be a regular one, but it isn't.

No matter what am I doing, the progress bar just not increasing.

In the base concept I have a GUI form and it has got a bacgroundworker. In the backgroundworker I am using a self defined class to read out the data from a measurement file. I want to increase the progress bar when it is done with one file, but no matter what am I doig it does nothing.

I have read the documentation but nothing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-value-displayed-by-the-windows-forms-progressbar-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I have tried:

`worker.ReportProgress` method

`Controls.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{});`  method

Furhtermore tried the `Control.Update()` and `Control.Refress()` too, but these are not working too.

Please help!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `progressBar1.Value += 1;` is directly quoted from the article you linked. Did you try it?

Comment: In general, most people I know would suggest to not use Backgroundworker in new development in favor of the Task-async / IProgress. But without seeing any of the code it's hard to tell if a refactor of that scope is justified. You really need to add some code ... if it is relevant even, that would be great.

Comment: You tagged your question "asp.net" but probably you are asking for "winforms", or?

Comment: Have you handled the event for progress changing? It's a long time since I've used background workers but from memory there is an event on the background worker  that needs handling to process the progress change. When you do worker.ReportProgress it fires that event. You have to handle it otherwise it does nothing. In it you would update the progress bar as per above comment. (I'm assuming Winforms rather than asp.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the Progress bar won't update is that the UI cannot be updated from background threads.  Backgroundworker runs on a background thread, which keeps the UI responsive.

Three solutions:

1. In the backgroundworker, start a new Task that runs on the Main UI thread, and update the progress bar there.  This is bad coding, but there are other use cases where .InvokeRequired is valid.
2. Use backgroundworker ReportProgress.  In the ProgressChanged handler (which runs on the UI thread), update the progressbar as normal.
3. Rewrite your app to use the "await Function1()/ async Task Fuction1() pattern instead of Backgroundworker.  Here .InvokeRequired will likely be used.  You can also use EventHandlers to return responses to the caller.

Examples Follow

#1 Warning bad coding style!

```
private void bgw1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    await Task.Run( () =>
    {
        progressBar1.InvokeIfRequired( o =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        } );
    });
    ...
}


public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T obj, InvokeIfRequiredDelegate<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
    {
        if (obj.InvokeRequired)
        {
            obj.Invoke(action, new Object[] { obj });
        }
        else
        {
            action(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

#2 This way works well:

```
private void bgw1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    worker.ReportProgress(0, 50);   //50% progress out of 100
    ...
}

private void bgw1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.UserState is Int32 i)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = i;
    }
}
```

#3

```
Is a complete re-write and likely outside the scope of your question.
```

Remember to mark this as an answer if it helps you.